# PHP Fatal error: Class 'MatthiasMullie\Minify\CSS' not found

Tags: php, class, minify, autoloader

I am trying to implement minify and I have the below code and error. Minify folder is in the same as the index.php

CODE:

```
<?php
require_once 'minify/src/Minify.php';
require_once 'minify/src/JS.php';
require_once 'minify/src/Exception.php';

use MatthiasMullie\Minify;

$cssMin = new Minify\CSS('assets/css/myCssFile.css');
```

Error in error_log file:

`[23-Jan-2018 05:14:12 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error: Class 'MatthiasMullie\Minify\CSS' not found in /home/johannes/public_html/2018/index.php on line 8`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have tried a few possible solutions posted here but they all failed. I cannot use the `autoloader` because of the permissions on the server but I hope I can use the files directly.

Comment: have you tried without `use MatthiasMullie\Minify;`?

Comment: @Machavity - I don't see how these two questions are the same. The one you refer to as a duplicate is not even mentioning the `Class Not Found` problem. Please remove the down vote.

Comment: @RamRaider - Yes I tried. Unfortunately the examples, and steps of getting this right, are not fully shown or explained. I thought the `CSS` class was primarily part of the `Minify` file, and that the `JS` class was an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to require CSS.php:

`require_once 'minify/src/CSS.php';`

Comment: Yep, that's the issue.